# MockMultipartFile cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, file, maven, spring-boot

I am writing code for a spring program, and I need to convert a `File` object to a `MultipartFile` object. I am trying to do this by using the `MockMultipartFile` class:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(toUpload);
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
                toUpload.getName(), "text/json", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

However, I keep getting the error `MockMultipartFile cannot be resolved to a type`. Why is this? If it helps, I'm using Maven, in case it may be a dependency error that I don't know about.

I also tried to do this using `CommonsMultipartFile`. That code is here (`toUpload` is the `File` object I am trying to convert):

```
DiskFileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "text/plain", false, toUpload.getName(), (int) toUpload.length() , toUpload.getParentFile());
fileItem.getOutputStream();
MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

When I try this method, I get the error `The constructor CommonsMultipartFile(DiskFileItem) is undefined`. Why is that?

EDIT: Here is our pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-uploading-files</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Post your `pom.xml`..Anyway you should add `spring-web` dependency, if it's not already there

Comment: @AliDehghani I posted our pom.xml if that helps, and ok I'll try to add the spring web dependency and see if it works.

Comment: Can you post stracktrace?

Answer (score 16):

To use spring's `MockMultipartFile` you need to add `spring-test` as a compile dependency (which would be unusual, since it is generally used as a test dependency):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is it good practice to use MockMultipartFile then? Doesn't sound like it should be used in production

Comment: I guess that MultipartFile is supposed to only be used when handling file uploads from client to server. In all other scenarios it makes more sense to use other forms of objects to represent streaming content - unfortunately, this is not an option if you program against a library that expects you to pass it a MultipartFile. I guess in that case it should not be difficult to create your own implementation of MultipartFile - I started by looking at MockMultipartFile implementation itself.

Comment: Addign this dependency worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use File change to MultipartFile, it can be transferred successfully using the below code

```
    File uploadFile = new File("src/main/resources/static/images/icon/icon4.jpg");
    FileInputStream is =  new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    return new MockMultipartFile("icon4.jpg", "icon4.jpg", "image/jpeg", IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
```